# Error SQL query: UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id =0 WHERE code = 'admin';

Tags: magento2, 404-page

i am using this code to resolve error 404 admin page problem

```
     SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `core_store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `core_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

but i have this error message

> Error
>
> ```
> SQL query:
>
> UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id =0 WHERE code = 'admin';
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
> #1146 - Table 'tests_maga.core_store' doesn't exist
> ```

help me please

Comment: Stating the obvious here but clearly the core_store table doesn't exist. Have you checked the database you are querying to ensure that the magento tables are there? are you using table prefixes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

```
UPDATE `store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `store_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
```

Comment: mysql accepted my code with your help , but now i have this error again ! what can i do ? 404 Not Found !